# Odoo 10 - update external ID

Tags: odoo-10

I would like to be able to update the external ID of a record.

Say for example that you create a UOM (Unit of Measure) or a provider.
You will get things like `__export__.product_uom_20`

If you want later to use that reference in a CSV import, you might want to rename the external ID to something more friendly before doing the import, such as: `__export__.product_uom_myspecialbox`. So the CSV becomes more meaningful.

Is is possible to modify the external ID of a given record in Odoo 10? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the external ID on the UI by going to

```
Settings -> Technical ->  Sequences and Identifiers -> External Identifiers
```

And there you just need to modify the `name` field once you found the record you want to modify.

If you want to do this programatically, you will need to modify the `ir.model.data` object, for example:

```py
env['ir.model.data'].search(
            [('name', '=' old_external_id)]).name = new_external_id
```

Where `env` is an `odoo.api.Environment` object with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: hello milan, I have question related to external identifiers. In Settings -> Technical ->  Sequences and Identifiers -> External Identifiers, can we create a new external identifier? if yes how can i? and another question is can we create a new record in any module(lets say crm) from Settings -> Technical ->  Sequences and Identifiers -> External Identifiers while creating a new external identifier? please help me on this.